# locate media source of playing medie wp

Tags: windows-phone-7, streaming, media, airplay

does Anybody know if it is possible to capture the media you are playing on windows phone, so you can stream it to another source,
Just like apple does with airplay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible to write a 3rd party app that can capture audio or video from other apps and stream it somewhere else.

Airplay on iOS is a system level service that apps can use.

The closest thing Windows Phone has is [Play To](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/play-to/8257b398-f4bf-4483-97c7-6fd6a1e60bbf), which allows you to pick existing media on the phone (pictures, music, video, etc) and share it to a compatible device. Currently, this technology isn't available to developers.

Comment: @DaCh there's always hope in future versions of the OS, such as Windows Phone 8.1 due early next year.